# How to do type conversions in c?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, typeconverter

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a, b, h, area, perimeter;
float pi;

void rectangle() {
    printf("enter rectangular base length");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter rectangular base height\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    area = a * b;
    perimeter = (a + b) * 2;
    printf("area of a rectangle = %d\n", area);
    printf("perimeter of a rectangle = %d", perimeter);
}

void circle() {
    pi = 3.14;
    printf("enter the length of the circle radius\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    area = pi * a * a;
    perimeter = 2 * pi * a;
    printf("area of the circle = %d\n", area); //I want this part to conversion from int to float
    printf("perimeter of the circle = %d", perimeter);
}

int main() {
    printf("Choose which way you will operate\n");
    printf("circle=1\nrectangle=2\n");
    scanf("%d", &h);

    switch (h) {
      case 1:
        printf("you chose a circle\n");
        circle();
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("you chose a rectangle\n");
        rectangle();
        break;
    }
}
```

As I wrote in the code, I want the part I specified to be converted from int to float. How can I do it?
I was know like that but it didn't work -> `(float)area = a * b;`

Comment: `area = a * b;` are all `int`. You need to make `float area;`. Although `int * int` equals `int`. Later, at `area = pi * a * a;` you need to make `area` a float since `pi` is a `float`.

Comment: If you declare `area` as `float`, it will convert automatically, you don't need a cast.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to define PI as a constant.  Prefer to minimize scope of variables (now local to the function that needs them).  Use floating point types (float, double etc) when needed to store fractional values with more than integer precision. Make sure you use the `%f` to print them (optionally, specify how many digits you want to see here %.1f means 1 fractional digit):

```
#define PI 3.14

void circle() {
    printf("enter the length of the circle radius\n");
    float a;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    float area = PI * a * a;
    float perimeter = 2 * pi * a;
    printf("area of the circle = %.1f\n", area);
    printf("perimeter of the circle = %.1f", perimeter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that your code here:

```
area = pi * a * a;
```

where "pi" you defined it as a float constant, so compiler will warn at this line something like "assign float to a integer", **you should know that no matter how many integers in a formula, even one float number in it, the type of final value will be automatically converted to float**
means the result of:

```
pi * a * a
```

will be a float (or double) value. But you assign this value to a int variable "area", so that value then cast to int.So you should declare area as:

```
float area; // or double area
```

By your comment in this line:

```
printf("area of the circle = %d\n", area); //I want this part to conversion from int to float
```

I guess you want to print a number with decimal part.

You can try this:

```
printf("area of the circle = %.3f\n", area);
```

".3" after "%" means print 3 decimal digits, or to say the precision is 3; "f" after ".3" means print argument 1 as a float number.

Comment: `int ... area` means that your cast will still only give you (approximately) integer values.

Comment: @Allan Wind that's right, I didn't noticed that at first when I write answer

Comment: Re "type of final value will be automatically converted to float". Yes, those vales will be automatically converted to floating point type during the arithmetic calculations, but  then truncated to an integer when stored in the `area` variable.